Typescript overload functions with two different object types
I want to find a way to create a type for a overload function like this:
function onClick({ids: string[], type: string}): void
function onClick({id: string}): void

As you can see here I need a function that could accept {id: string[], type: string} or {id: string} but not any other combination.
I already tried:
type OnClick = (({ids, type }:{ids: string[], type: string}) => void) | (({id}:{id:string}) => void)

---

 type Params<T> = T extends { id: string }
  ? T
  : { ids: string[], type: string };

type OnClick = <T>(params: Params<T>) => void

And multiple variations of it and always receive the same error either id is missing the following properties from type '{ ids: string[]; type: string; }' or the other way around.
Any idea on how to solve it?

Your example at the top is pseudocode; it's not valid syntax so I'm not sure what you're asking exactly. • What is TypeOptions? • Where exactly are you seeing the error you're describing? • Could you make sure that everything that's meant to be an example is as correct TS as you can make it? That way we can jump right to trying to answer the question and not spend extra time trying to understand it.

"As you can see here" What I see is an invalid function declaration. I can't tell if you forgot the parameter name, or if you added {, } in error. I'm supposing the former, but it would be really nice if you could [edit] so that we don't have to suppose.  I suggest you use an IDE to look at your code examples and make sure that the only problems with them are the ones you're asking about.

What stops you from writing like this: function onClick(argument: {ids: string[], type: string} | {id: string}): void?

@André
Thanks for answering, but I am receiving this error still
Type '({ id }: { id: string; }) => void' is not assignable to type '(argument: { id: string; } | { ids: string[]; type: string; }) => void'

@mgm793 See this playground link. See how at the top I added a parameter name to make this thing compile? If that's what you're talking about please fix the code in your question to match. Underneath I show you the types corresponding to the overloaded function you have. But if you have errors somewhere, you really need to put the code necessary to reproduce them in the question itself. Have I fully addressed the question? If so I'll write an answer after you fix the question. If not, please [edit] the question to include a [mre] of whatever's missing.
